# Play 2.4 Slick 3.0 - Delete all rows in table

Tags: scala, sql-delete, postgresql-9.4, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

I'm using Slick 3.0 to access a PostgreSQL database in Play 2.4 and need a way to delete all rows from a table without dropping it.

Deleting single rows works:

```
lazy val tasks = TableQuery[Tasks]

def delete(id: Long) = db.run(tasks.filter(_.id === id).delete)
```

But I can't figure out how to implement an empty where clause in slick to delete all rows. ([As seen in PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-delete.html))

The trivial solution `db.run(tasks.delete)` does not seem to do anything and there doesn't seem to be a `truncate` function available.

**Edit:**

`db.run(tasks.delete)` works, you just have to wait for the Future to complete. Truncating a table requires some SQL: `db.run(sqlu"TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY;")`.

Comment: Notice that `db.run` returns an future you have to wait for it to complete

Comment: If you are happy with your solution, please submit it as an answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got the answer, I would like to add that you can also use `Await.result` function from the `scala.concurrent` package in case you want to make the program wait for the db query to complete. The query goes something like this:

```
Await.result(db.run(sqlu"TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY;"),Duration.Inf))
```